# "Buffer full" exception when BufferedWaveProvider is being filled in another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, naudio

I have two BufferedWaveProviders and MixingSampleProvider. The first BufferedSampleProvider (`myBuffer`) is for my audio comming from soundcard. The second BufferedWaveProvider (`incomingBuffer`) is for audio comming from network (TCP).

`incomingBuffer` is being filled asynchronously like that:

```
    private static void Receive()
    {
        receiver.BeginReceive(incomingBytes, 0, incomingBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        receiver.EndReceive(ar);
        incomingBuffer.AddSamples(incomingBytes, 0 , incomingBytes.Length);
        Receive();
    }
```

But after 7-10 second after starting the program it finishes because of exception.

 How should I fill the buffer asynchronously?

Comment: What is your exception exactly? Please, put it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Stop ignoring the return value of EndReceive*.

It tells you how many bytes of data you received. That's how many samples you have to add to your buffer (though make sure that you're not converting samples to bytes and vice versa incorrectly).

Instead, now you're simply passing your `incomingBytes` to the `incomingBuffer` whole, always - even if you only received a single byte over TCP. This is garbage data, and it fills your buffer quicker than it can drain.

In general, return values of methods and functions are meaningful, and ignoring them should only be done when you understand *what* you're ignoring (e.g. if you don't care about handling anything but the callback, ignoring the return value of `BeginReceive` is fine; if you need to know whether there's a pending asynchronous I/O request, you need the return value).